# Is it possible to create a Filesystem TS basic_path from a range of path iterators or a subpath?

Tags: c++, stl, boost-filesystem

I'm trying to create a one-level deep subpath of a basic_path (`data/images/lol.png` -> `images/lol.png`).

I tried something like `std::path{ ++path.begin(), path.end() }` but the range constructor apparently needs `string_type::iterator`s, not `basic_path::iterator`s.

Is it possible for me to do what I need using `basic_path` methods, or will I have to use something like `std::accumulate( ++path.begin(), path.end() )` (pretty inefficient imho)?

Comment: I am courious what your problem with accumulate is. It seems like you don't have another choice anyway. Performance wise I think it can't be too bad considering that paths most of the time are less than 200 characters.

Comment: Sure, but performance-wise it's still a class slower (O(1) vs O(logn) allocations in the worst case), complexity-wise it's slower (O(1) vs O(n) in the worst case).

A path-iterator constructor is trivial to make as far as I'm aware, so it's weird to me that it's missing. Also from my admittedly bad memory, it's also the first instance in the standard library of a class with iterators that doesn't have a constructor that takes those iterators.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find was

```
path subpath(path p) {
  auto pathString = p.native();
  auto newBegin = find(pathString.begin(), pathString.end(), path::preferred_separator);
  return path{ ++newBegin, pathString.end() };
}
```

It only requires one allocation but its time complexity is still O(n), however I cannot imagine a way to speed it up any further.

It's still faster than accumulate (200 char path):

```
accumulate: 31386 ns ± 5336.29
my subpath: 785.857 ns ± 422.013
```